# Визуальное программирование на Unity. Доступ к кодовой базе

Tags: unity3d

Хочу создать еще одну систему визуального скриптинга. Пытаюсь уяснить некоторые вопросы.

Как можно получить в своем плагине редактора информацию о кодовой базе C#, а именно о всех существующих пространствах имен, публичных классах в них, публичных переменных и методах в этих классах?

Это нужно, чтобы можно было на основе этой информации создавать узлы (блоки) визуальной программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть в сторону встроенного механизма C# под названием Reflection (рефлексия). Подробней о ней вы можете почитать в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). 
Что касается ваших конкретных запросов:

- [Получение namespace в сборке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549198/finding-all-namespaces-in-an-assembly-using-reflection-dotnet)
- [Получение классов в сборке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-can-i-get-all-classes-within-a-namespace)
- [Получение методов в классе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475209/get-class-methods-using-reflection)
- [Получение полей в классе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649324/c-sharp-reflection-get-field-values-from-a-simple-class)

В коде данные вещи должны работать в unity, по крайней мере на практике пользовался получением полей и методов у класса. Что касается редактора - сложно сказать, что из этого выйдет, не до конца понятен ваш замысел, пробуйте.